# how to ceil and floor a Calendar Date by 10 minnutes?

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-9

there is a better way to round (ceil and floor) a date-time by ten minutes of the following code:

```
public void hintOfTime() {
        Date orario = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").parse(usaServizio_standard.setStr());
        // I have skipped the try catch for an easy read
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(orario);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if(minutes>=1 && minutes<=9) {
            usaServizio_standard.hint("not valid date","Try with: "+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":00 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":10");
        }else if(minutes>=11 && minutes<=19) {
            usaServizio_standard.hint("not valid date","Try with: "+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":10 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":20");
        }else if(minutes>=21 && minutes<=29) {
            usaServizio_standard.hint("not valid date","Try with: "+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":20 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":30");
        }else if(minutes>=31 && minutes<=39) {
            usaServizio_standard.consiglio("not valid date","Try with: "+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":30 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":40");
        }else if(minutes>=41 && minutes<=49) {
            usaServizio_standard.consiglio("not valid date","Try with "+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":40 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":50");
        }else {
            usaServizio_standard.hint("not valid date","Try with"+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+1)+":50 or "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR+2)+":00");
        }
    }
```

this solution works fine but is so ugly. I don't know if there is a better and short solution for doing the same works.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I'm certain there is a better way using previously mentioned time package.  It may involve doing some integer math like `(minutes/10)*10`.  `So minutes = 46, (46/10)*10 = 40`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work.

```
    String timeString = "09:56";
    
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
    int minute = time.getMinute();
    if (minute % 10 != 0) {
        // truncate to whole 10 minutes
        LocalTime firstSuggestedTime = time.withMinute(minute / 10 * 10);
        LocalTime secondSuggestedTime = firstSuggestedTime.plusMinutes(10);
        System.out.format("Not a valid time; try with %s or %s.%n",
                firstSuggestedTime, secondSuggestedTime);
    }
```

Output from this example was:

> Not a valid time; try with 09:50 or 10:00.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.